# Figure out last completed payment via Accounts.payments: list in AdSense Management API v1.4

Tags: adsense-api

I am successfully using Google's AdSense API to retrieve payments. The AdSense account I am testing the app with does not have any completed payments.

I am using [Accounts.payments:list](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/payments/list) to retrieve the payments and currently I am only getting one row with `Id = "unpaid"`. This entry specifies the amount that is available for payment.

My question here is what are the other possible entries in the result? Specifically how can I find last completed payment?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items[]` description: "*The list of Payments for the account. One or both of a) the account's most recent payment; and b) the account's upcoming payment*".

As far I can see `id` can be "unpaid", or date of the last payment (probably the "payment issued" date):

```
{
 "kind": "adsense#payments",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "adsense#payment",
   "id": "unpaid",
   "paymentAmount": "***.**",
   "paymentAmountCurrencyCode": "***"
  },
  {
   "kind": "adsense#payment",
   "id": "****-**-**",
   "paymentDate": "****-**-**",
   "paymentAmount": "***.**",
   "paymentAmountCurrencyCode": "***"
  }
 ]
}
```

> how can I find last completed payment?

In my understanding, that is exactly what `Accounts.payments:list` is (or will be) returning:

- your account current balance
- last payment (if there was any)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the documentation states that there are at most two entries expected. I have missed that. Let me verify and get back with confirmation.